# Как скрыть проверку внешних ссылок сервисами?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, ссылки, robots.txt

Как запретить/спрятать проверку внешних ссылок на сайт от Ahrefs, megaindex и прочих сервисов? Для ботов, конечно все должно быть доступно.

Comment: Ahrefs, megaindex и прочие сервисы вообще-то собирают информацию тоже с помощью ботов, так что наверно никак. Или разве что они могут иметь честные методы выключения, почитайте их справки

Comment: я точно знаю что можно скрыть, в топе по нехилым запросам есть сайты где ни мега и ни ахрефс не находит внешние ссылки

Comment: Почитайте их robots.txt например?

Comment: запрятали, 404 отдает, при попытке найти и прочесть все txt - то же самое, хорошо замаскировались :)

Comment: Ну вот у Ahrefs например в справке написано, как их бота отключить https://ahrefs.com/ru/robot

Comment: круто, спасибо большое! не думал что можно даже так :))